# [encoder encodeValuesOfObjCTypes - what do i put here?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

This is what i've tried so far, as suggested by various websites:

```
[encoder encodeValuesOfObjCTypes:@encode(BOOL), self.isInPhotoLibrary];
[encoder encodeValuesOfObjCTypes:"i", self.isInPhotoLibrary];
[encoder encodeValuesOfObjCTypes:(const char *)self.isInPhotoLibrary];
```

All of these 3 crash. Anybody know how to use this? self.isInPhotoLibrary is a BOOL.

Comment: I would love to know what "various websites" you're looking at, since these are all wrong, especially the last one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation for `-encodeValuesOfObjCTypes:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSCoder/encodeValuesOfObjCTypes%3a) states:

> The variable arguments to this method consist of one or more pointer
>   arguments, each of which specifies a buffer containing the value to be
>   encoded. For each type code in valueTypes, you must specify a
>   corresponding pointer argument.

You are passing in a value, not a pointer.  Do this instead:

```
BOOL value = self.isInPhotoLibrary;
[encoder encodeValuesOfObjCTypes:@encode(BOOL), &value];
```

Or, since you're encoding only one value:

```
BOOL value = self.isInPhotoLibrary;
[encoder encodeValueOfObjCType:@encode(BOOL) at:&value];
```

Answer (score 5):

I think it'd be simpler to use the [keyed archiving method](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000293-BCIEAHDA):

```
[encoder encodeBool:[self isInPhotoLibrary] forKey:@"isInPhotoLibrary"];
```